WS2811 data line voltage level
I tried to control WS2811 LED strip with 12 V power line.
After testing my ESP32 program I connect the strip with a ground and data cable. The power (12 V) was only connected to the strip.
My ESP32 immediately stopped working. It appeared that there was 12 V on the data line, which burnt ESP32.
The question is: is it expected to have 12 V on the data line?

I just made a board where I supply the WS2812b with 5V. I tested it wil 3,3V and won't turn on properly. As others said the maximum voltage (at least of the WS2812b) is 5.3V, sou you most likely damaged your unit supplying it with 12V

No it is not expected. If you look at a typical datasheet for the chip itself the input levels are 0.3 and 0.7 times Vdd, which is maximum 5.5V (minimum 4.5V) and comes from an internal shunt regulator.
The maximum input current is also < 1uA so it is supposed to behave more-or-less like an open circuit for inputs between GND and Vdd.
So '0' is < 1.35V (4.5V Vdd) and '1' is > 3.85V, so it cannot necessarily be driven reliably directly by a 3.3V MCU.
If the ground was not properly connected to the strip then bad things(tm) could certainly happen because that would conduct current through the protection diodes in the chip.

I was ready 3 3v is not enough to control the strip. But I wasn't ready there would be a current flowing from the data line to the ESP32.

There should not be. Bad connection? Bad strip?

"The power (12 V) was only connected to the strip" and "If the ground was not properly connected to the strip" ... if you connected only +12v (not ground), then the data line could / would indeed come up to +12v, and may be able to source some current.

Both ground and 12v from a power source were connected to the strip. The data wire from the strip was connected to EESP32 as well as common ground.

@VladM Could always be a damaged or defective strip, for example a short or a broken trace within the strip caused by a manufacturing defect or a sharp or repeated bend in the flex.
